# Is it possible to extract the contents of a tar file to two directories at the same time with a single command?

Tags: linux, scripting

What I was curious about is whether I can use a version of the command
`tar -xvf fileName.tar`
to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ./directory0
mkdir ./directory1
path="directory"
for catalog in ./"$path"*
do
  tar -xvf fileName.tar -C $catalog
done
```

Comment: Looks interesting.

Comment: Can't I also specify the directories after the filename?

Comment: @Sofia190, As you know the command ```tar``` has the next syntax ```tar [key-parameters] [archive-file] [file or directory to be archived]```. To extract a tar file, just issue the following command using the key-parameter ```x``` (extract). For example, the below command will extract the file ```fileName.tar``` in the concrete directory ```directory0```: ```user@userdesktop:~$ tar -xvf fileName.tar -C ./directory0```. If you want to extract your file in the concrete directory then use the key-parameter ```-C``` (specified directory).

Comment: I'm thinking to write many variants of a script.

Comment: Maybe the directories exist.